# Chrome driver throwing "org.openqa.selenium.remote.SessionNotFoundException" when running selenium tests heedlessly in linux?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, xvfb

Environment: Centos7, Chromedriver2.24, chrome-browser-stable version 2.53, selenium version 2.53.1 and xvfb

When running tests parallel with 8 concurrent threads giving session not found exception..

Chrome-setup:

```
                DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
                capabilities.setCapability("chrome.switches", Arrays.asList(
                        "--disable-logging", "--silent", "--log-level 3"));
                capabilities.setCapability("chrome.logfile", "NUL");
                capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.ACCEPT_SSL_CERTS, true);
                capabilities.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, options);
                System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver",
                        "servers/chromedriver-local");
                driver = new ChromeDriver(capabilities);
```

Any help much appreciated!!

Comment: Having the same problem on Ubuntu running tests single-threaded via cucumber and Geb. This error starts to appear mid-way through the build, then occurs on every test

Comment: Found solution here: https://github.com/elgalu/docker-selenium/issues/20 answered by @elgalu `Simpy mount -v /dev/shm:/dev/shm`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what fixed my issue:

Simpy `mount -v /dev/shm:/dev/shm`

Or, longer, create a big shm

Started in privileged mode: docker run --privileged
Fix small /dev/shm size

```
docker exec $id sudo umount /dev/shm
docker exec $id sudo mount -t tmpfs -o rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,size=512M tmpfs /dev/shm
```

However it would be nice to avoid privileged mode.

(Ref:github.com/elgalu/docker-selenium/issues/20)